# Is it really necessary to use fstrim on Samsung SM843T SSDs?

Tags: ssd, trim

Should we schedule periodical fstrims on Samsung SSD drives?

What happens if we don't run such periodical scripts?

I am highlighting the model on the Title because I am assuming that the answer is model/manufacturer specific.

What we are using:

2 SSDs Samsung model SM843T 
Centos 7.1

Comment: Now I found the time to read through the details regarding the question I posted a link to, and I posted an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/686597/284919) to that question as well. Turns out it was not related to Samsung SSDs as originally assumed but rather to a bug in how the Linux RAID-0 implementation uses TRIM.

Answer (score 2):

Over time, SSD's will start to degrade because when they write and erase a lot, it will not be able to tell which blocks have been erased so it moves on to new fresh locations, and this will cause fragmentation. So eventually it just writes to the whole SSD, after which it will start 'write amplification.' Meaning that it will have to go through a cycle of read-erase-modify-write for every write, this is what slows it down.

So depending on your machine, as in how much read/write you will be doing and the SSD's capacity, I would say it is not necessary for now. But later on, it would not hurt to start fstrim.

Edit* - I do not think its vendor specific. I didn't find anything wrong with this model of SSD. But my answer above is for all SSD's in general.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Caesartcs. So If I understand this correctly, it is an optional performance enhancer. And the SSD can continue with its operations as usual without us running any fstrims. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Over time however, like everything else, it will slow down, perhaps. When you feel that that happens, then feel free to fstrim it.